# How to List all indexed columns for a given table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

Is there a way that I can list all the columns that have an index in MySQL based on the table

For e.g. something like

```
 select indexes where table_name='Person';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wanting to use [SHOW INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html).

This is a pretty simple line so it does not need much explanation.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM table;
```

or

```
SHOW INDEX FROM database.table;
```

or

```
SHOW INDEX FROM table FROM database;
```

For some better reading on the SELECT statement check out [Extensions to SHOW Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/extended-show.html)

There is another nifty way to list all indexes by utilizing the [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) database.

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT * FROM statistics;
```

See [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA STATISTICS Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/statistics-table.html)